# Finding power spectrum given the autocorrelation of the function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm struggling to see how to solve for a particular power spectrum given an autocorrelation function. I understand the Wiener-Khinchin theorem provides me with the fact that the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function (which is given) is equal to the power spectrum of the function:

$$
F[R_{gg}(t)] = S_{gg}(t)
$$

where $ R_{gg}(t) $ is the autocorrelation function and $ S_{gg} $ is the power spectrum.

The equation that I am given:

$$
R(\tau) = 1 - |\tau|,\ |\tau| \leq 1 \\ 
R(\tau) = 0\ \text{in all other cases}
$$

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I should begin to deal with this?